# Perl parse json with array inside

Tags: arrays, json, perl, hash

Hi I am new to perl and parsing json. Below is a json output from DB API.

```
{
  "limit": 50,
  "page": 1,
  "result": [
    {
      "var1": "var1_1",
      "var2": "var2_1",
      "created_at": "2019-10-06T15:52:37.705950+00:00",
      "id": 2,
      "updated_at": "2019-10-06T15:52:37.705950+00:00",
      "var3": "var3_1"
    },
    {
      "var1": "var1_2",
      "var2": "var2_2",
      "created_at": "2019-10-06T14:17:35.951395+00:00",
      "id": 1,
      "updated_at": "2019-10-06T14:17:35.951395+00:00",
      "var3": "var3_1"
      }
    ],
  "success": true,
  "total_results": 2
}
```

How to get var1 from latest ID (here 2).?

I tried like this below.

```
    use LWP::Simple;
    $contents = get($db_url);
    print "$contents\n";  # print the above output
    my $fromjson = from_json($contents);
    my $data1 = $fromjson->{'limit'};
    print "$data1"; # print properly 50
    my $data2 = $fromjson->{'result'};
    my $data1 = to_json($data2);
    my $data_var1=$data1->{'var1'}; # Tried like this but not getting proper output
```

Kindly help I tried different ways but not getting through.

Comment: Note: `from_json` (accepts decoded text) should be `decode_json` (accepts text encoded using UTF-8)

Comment: @ikegami Not necessarily, LWP::Simple uses decoded_content which may be decoded from UTF-8 already depending on the content-type header. To be consistent I'd rather use content and decode_json of course, I wouldn't recommend LWP::Simple in general.

Answer (score 2):

`my $data2 = $fromjson->{'result'};` returns an array reference. You can learn about references in [Perl Reference Tutorial](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.30.0/perlreftut.html).

If you just want the first item in the results, first fetch the array ref.

```
my $results = $fromjson->{result};
```

Then the first result, which is a hash reference.

```
my $first_result = $results->[0];
```

And finally get the value of the `var1` key.

```
my $var1 = $first_result->{var1};
```

You can also chain this together, though it makes error handling harder.

```
my $var1 = $from_json->{result}[0]{var1};
```

Comment: Note: This assumes the first record is the latest record.

Comment: Note: This assumes there's always at least one result.